# How do i call a label inside a viewcell from the code behind

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This is my listview and bascially I want the text that is being shown on screen in a variable. So usually you would just put **x:Name = "Pair"** in the label and then behind you would write **var pair = Pair.Text;** but in this case, that does not work. My expected result would be the text that is presented on screen in a variable.

```
<ListView x:Name="myPriceList" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="False" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Label Text="{Binding Pair}" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black" FontSize="15" Margin="0,0,0,-5"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding buyPrice}" TextColor="DarkSlateGray" FontSize="13" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding buyAmount}" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black" FontSize="17" Margin="0,0,0,-5" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding worth}" TextColor="DarkSlateGray" FontSize="13" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: the text shown in the Labels are data-bound from the model, so you can get their value from the model.  You cannot access items in a template by name.

Comment: @Jason Alright Thanks!